# binding datetime in knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js, event-handling, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried all possility I can come across but a datepicker is not firing an update on my view model. Searching around I could put together the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindings.get('options') || {
            format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
            defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
        };

        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

       ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) 
       {
           var value = valueAccessor();
           if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
              value(event.date);
           }
       });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); //I can see the initial value when page first load

        if (widget) {
            widget.date = value;
            if (widget.date) {
                $(element).datetimepicker({
                    date: value
                });
            }
       }
    }
};


var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

// continue with some tweaking

 // DateOfThing comes from c# DateTime type

 // on console window
 // ko.isObservable(viewModel.DateOfThing) // = true

  vm.DateOfThing.subscribe(function(){
    // never fires
  }
```

binding:

```
<input asp-for="DateOfThing" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: DateOfThing" />
```

I can see the handler being called when the page first load, but the UI is not updated. I can picking a date thereafter, but only UI gets updated. I've tried all the possibilities I can come across with no success.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/), they've already given a section for creating a Knockout handler. Try comparing this to yours? In particular, the name of event `dp.change`, instead of `changeDate`.

> ```
> ko.bindingHandlers.dateTimePicker = {
>     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
>         //initialize datepicker with some optional options
>         var options = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || {};
>         $(element).datetimepicker(options);
>
>         //when a user changes the date, update the view model
>         ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
>             var value = valueAccessor();
>             if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
>                 if (event.date != null && !(event.date instanceof Date)) {
>                     value(event.date.toDate());
>                 } else {
>                     value(event.date);
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>
>         ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
>             var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
>             if (picker) {
>                 picker.destroy();
>             }
>         });
>     },
>     update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
>
>         var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
>         //when the view model is updated, update the widget
>         if (picker) {
>             var koDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
>
>             //in case return from server datetime i am get in this form for example /Date(93989393)/ then fomat this
>             koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(parseFloat(koDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))) : koDate;
>
>             picker.date(koDate);
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

Comment: I get the error `onChangeDateTime is not recognized`

Comment: Lol.. would have been nice if you had mentioned that at first.
Anyway, the documentation for your plugin has a section for Knockout http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/ . The change event is called 'dp.change'. So why are you using `changeDate` as the event?

Comment: Yes. though I had to teak it a bit. `koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(parseFloat(koDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))) : koDate;` didn't cut it for me. Also the date was being saved in `Utc` which also kinda threw me off the cliff. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction, that was a breakthrough.